# defining class variables in method?

Tags: php, class, oop, variables, methods

Every example I've seen for defining a variable in a class, does so outside of any methods, for example:

```
class Testclass
{
  public $testvar = "default value";

  function dosomething()
  {
    echo $this->testvar;
  }
}

$Testclass = new Testclass();
$Testclass->testvar = "another value";    
$Testclass->dosomething();
```

How would you go about defining a variable inside a method, and making that definition available to any other method inside that class?

Note that I would only want to define the variable in one function, not have a different definition for each function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should read up on good object oriented practices. I mean, why do you want to make a variable available "inside a method"?

Variable's created within methods are local to that specific method and as such, scope is restricted to it.

You should instead use a instance member/variable which is available object wide if your trying to access a variable between methods. Or possibly you could pass the variable by ref between methods. Of course if its a value which never changes then it should be static variable on the class (class member).

I suggest having a read of the the OO tutorial on tutsplus. Tutsplus are generally great quality. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762

Alternatively, you could do the OO python course (intro to computer science) on Udacity - its also very high quality. Don't worry that its Python, specific language and syntax is irrelevant when trying to understand core OO concepts. https://www.udacity.com/course/cs101

Also, this is a common topic so have a search around, ie [Passing Variables between methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499785/passing-variables-between-methods)

I hope that helps

**Edit:** to address your comment. something like this:

```
class Testclass
{
  private $csvResult = []; // instance member array to store csv results

  function dosomething()
  {
    $this->$csvResult = fgetcsv($blah);
  }

  function processResult()
  {
    foreach ($this->$csvResult as $item) {
      var_dump($item)
    }
  }
}
```

But again, as Adrian Cid Almaguer mentioned, you really are best to build a solid foundation of OO for yourself instead of just using this example without truly understanding it.

Comment: Well, I have a very specific need, I'm attempting to parse values from a csv file using fgetcsv, and I need the values returned to be shared with other methods, which need them to perform their task. 

As far as I know, you can't use any filesystem functions outside of a function argument.

Comment: check my edit above, you should certainly use a instance variable to hold the results of your csvparsing, it will be available "object wide". again if you do not understand the concepts of object wide, encapsulation, instance variable, class variables, scope etc etc, then as @Adrian Cid Almaguer mentions, you really should read up on OO. do some tutorials :) Goodluck mate

Answer (score 1):

The real name of the variables class is "properties". You may also see them referred to using other terms such as "attributes" or "fields". In OOP (Object Oriented Programming) You can't define a property inside a method (the real name of a class function is method, not function), because this is a attribute of a class, not an attribute
of a method.

The properties define the attributes of a class, and the methods defines the behavior of a class. For example if you have a class named Person, the person have Name and Age, they are your properties, they are the attributes that describe your class, they can't be inside a method that describe a behavior of your class because the properties of your class must be accessed from any method that need it to show his behavior.

You can read some examples in:

> http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/

Comment: Alright, well I'm a little confused then as to how I would go about for example, parsing a csv file using fgetcsv, and defining the values received, then sharing them with other methods so they can perform their task.

Comment: @Kreation, do you mean you want to share the results of the array resulting from fgetcsv? You would just have that array as a class member. `private $csvResult = [];`, ie that sits outside the methods

Comment: @Kreation I think that you need read some docs about OOP, and read the wired00 comment